# Why my query take 13 sec on mongoose and 0.7 sec with robomongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to execute this simple query on a collection of ~100K documents:

```
db.foobar.find().sort({ score: -1 })
```

My documents are smalls:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("566acb77ddf99fd8989fafed"),
    "score" : 123,
    "username" : "John Smith"
}
```

I use Robomongo to test some queries on my database and I execute the mentioned query in an average respond time of **0.7 sec**

I tried to execute the same query in a static function of mongoose.

Here is my code:

```
leaderboardSchema.statics.getRank = function (callback) {
    var query = this.find().sort({ score: -1 });

    query.exec(function (err, records) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        callback(null, records);
    });
};
```

But when I execute the query I have to wait **13 seconds** to get the result !

What am I missing ? Why it's so long with mongoose and not with Robomongo ?

Comment: isn't your code inside a loop? Is your connection to the server correct? Is your server a standalone or a replicat set?

Comment: Try adding `lean()` to your query. As in `query.lean().exec(...`

Comment: @ConstantinGuay I'm testing my code locally on my computer. I just type the url in my browser and use morgan with node to log the server request. The onyl thing I see is my api call once without any loop insine ( `GET /api/leaderboard/rank   200   12172.588 ms`)

Comment: And i you add a `return 'test'` before your `query.exec`, is it faster? (This, to check if the problem comes from Mongo call or not)

Comment: @JohnnyHK Oh nice! It's 2sc instead of 13 now, not so bad :)

Comment: @ConstantinGuay Without the .exec I get 'test' in ~3 ms

Comment: RoboMongo is also only fetching the first 50 or so results from the cursor, right?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Hmmm... yes probably. Inly the 50 first are displayed so may be there is a `.limit(50)` "hidden".

Comment: It's not a hidden `limit` call, it's just that RoboMongo stops getting more docs from the native cursor after 50, while Mongoose reads them all.

Comment: If you don't do that already, specifying "score" as a secondary index could vastly improve your query's speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two factors here:

1. With Mongoose, it's important to use the [`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) option for queries with large results sets when all you need is the JavaScript object representation of the documents and not full Mongoose document instances.
2. RoboMongo is only reading the first 50 results (by default) from the results of the query, while Mongoose reads all 100K.